# Extract hour from timestamp in string format on bigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a timestamp that is in the string format that looks like `2010-02-02T07:54:40Z`. How can I get the `HOUR` from this timestamp?

I tried `SELECT dt, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dt) FROM table` but I am getting this error:

```
No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM STRING. Supported signatures: EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATE); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIMESTAMP [AT TIME ZONE STRING]); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATETIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM INTERVAL)
```

How do I get the `HOUR` from `2010-02-02T07:54:40Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to cast string as timestamp and then need to extract hour.
I have replicated issue in my project and here is the solution.

Query part- ( ts_string is column name with string datatype)
EXTRACT(hour
FROM
CAST(ts_string AS timestamp)) AS hour_extracted
[image]